# JQuery fails to load when i use a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm incorporating PHP code into JQuery like this:

```
                echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var count = ($('.data').length + 25);
                    /* This is the line */var c = $c;
                    $('#data').load('data.php?v=' + count + '&c=' + c)
                    $('.btn-data').click(function() {
                        count = count + 25;
                        $('#data').load('data.php?v=' + count + '&c=' + c)
                    })
                })</script>";
```

The PHP variable shows as blue, there are no errors showing, but when I run it it refuses to work. I've tested everything else and I'm 100% sure PHP is the one causing the problem.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you open your browser console and refresh the page do you see any errors?

Comment: What is the variable `$c`? Is it a string, number, object ?

Comment: I do not see you actually writing out the variable in php. It is just part of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$c` is your php variable you will need to quote and join it inside an `echo` tag.

But as [Carton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12685897/carlton) (+1) said, is it a `string`, `integer`, `object`?

If it's an `integer`, this should work...

```
<?php

echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
          $(document).ready(function() {
          var count = ($('.data').length + 25);
          var c = " . $c . ";
          $('#data').load('data.php')
             $('.btn-data').click(function() {
                 count = count + 25;
                  $('#data').load('data.php?v=' + count + '&c=' + c)
             })
          });
      </script>";
```

If it's a `string` this should work...

```
<?php

echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
          $(document).ready(function() {
          var count = ($('.data').length + 25);
          var c = '" . $c . "';
          $('#data').load('data.php')
             $('.btn-data').click(function() {
                 count = count + 25;
                  $('#data').load('data.php?v=' + count + '&c=' + c)
             })
          });
      </script>";
```

If it's an `object`, you will have to parse the var or encode it.

---

Sometimes if you want to echo or return big blocks of html inside php, you can use an [output buffer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to capture the html, and then you can either return the html via a function, or echo it. This just makes your html easier to read when it's not wrapped inside echo quotes tags.

```
<?php

// c sting php var 
$c = 'string';

// start output buffer
ob_start();

?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        let count = ($('.data').length + 25);
        let c = '<?=$c?>';
        $('#data').load('data.php');
        $(this).on('click', '.btn-data', function() {
            count = count + 25;
            $('#data').load('data.php?v=' + count + '&c=' + c);
        });
    });
</script>

<?php

// store everything between ob_start() and here into a php variable
$script = ob_get_clean();

// return script html
return $script;

// or echo script html
echo $script;

// not both together obviously

?>
```

Comment: No worries, I've including an option in answer using [php output buffer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) which might be useful.

Comment: You don't need to concatenate `$c` if you're using double quotes. The problem probably comes from the fact that $c is a string and create an invalid JS declaration `var c = foo` instead of `var c = 'foo'`

Comment: @docl oh cool really, never realised this. My answer is pretty bad then. Cheers for spotting, you should post as an answer maybe or I can update my answer with your observations?

Comment: Kudos for showing the code the way you did inside the buffering-- this unclutters the code and helps debugging-- but I would suggest the next step and never output anything until the PHP processing is done.